# Proper course of action for (possibly) incorrect migrations?

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked a question on SO that was very quickly migrated to TeX.SE. I re-examined the question and tried to see how it belong on TeX.SE, but I just can't see how it fits there.

What is the recommended course of action for situations like these? Is posting it to meta correct?

---

In the specific, the question is, [Plugin (vim-latex) crashing gVim on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034254/vim-latex-crashing-gvim-on-startup-migrated).

If you read through it, it is clear that it may as well be titled "vim plugin crashing gvim on startup." People who have in-depth knowledge of LaTeX are much less likely to be able to help me than people who know vim. I think it was skimmed over and moved a bit prematurely.

The same person who initially suggested that the question should be migrated to TeX.SE also suggested it should go to Super User, because vim questions don't belong on SO. I would like to refute that here since I didn't get the chance before it was moved. [Vim questions: do they belong to Stack Overflow or Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su)

If I should rephrase my question or title so that it is more clear it isn't especially LaTeX-related I am more than willing to do that.

Why do I care either way? Well, I want a solution to my question, and so I want to ask it to the best audience. There are 5 users who follow the "vim" tag on TeX.SE and 2900 users who follow it on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the future, flag the SO version for mod attention and explain why it shouldn't have been migrated (in this case Jeff already unmigrated it). They can clear the migration history and get a TeX mod to delete the migrated copy

Comment: Okay, I'll do this in the future. Actually, while we're on that topic.. Attempting to visit the SO version redirected me to the TeX.SE version (which makes sense to do). The problem is: how do I flag the SO version if I can't actually view it? I flagged the one on TeX.SE, but I don't think the moderators there can do much on SO, right?

Comment: @Nick They can contact the SO mods (mods from both sites are going to need to be involved either way). In either case, on the TeX.SE version there'd be a box that says "migrated from stackoverflow.com" -- the "stackoverflow.com" is a link to the SO version of the post that won't redirect (it adds `?noredirect=1` to the URL)

Comment: Ahh, now that's all cleared up for me, thanks very much. :)

Comment: @NickKnowlson Belatedly - if you click on the "Migrated from" link on the receiving site, you'll see that the link includes the query string `noredirect=1`, allowing you to view and flag the original question, for example: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/asp-net-mvc-3-0-scaffolding-access-control?noredirect=1