# Timeline doesn't include migration information

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, timeline

I was reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102032/proper-course-of-action-for-possibly-incorrect-migrations), and I got the paranoias that I was the one that screwed up.  So, I hopped over to the question to see who migrated it.  Checking out the timeline, I see

[image: timeline page]

nothing about who migrated and where it was migrated.  I believe this information should be in the timeline.

Comment: Is it possible this would be an issue in the data?  I'm not sure how we are storing stuff on the back end but I imagine this might include a cross-DB or cross-Server query.

Comment: Yeah, it seems inconsistent that this information is in the history view, but not the timeline (although it's in neither in this case since Jeff cleared the migration, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of implied in the [original version](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/27153/timeline) of the question, but only through my misreading of the information, and only if the question stays migrated:

[image: Looked like migration information was included...]

But there's no details on the [receiving timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9750998/timeline) at all about it's migration.

Answer (score 1):

The new timeline we released now includes migration events within it, which will indicate where it was to/from and the site involved (with a link to the original/new question on that site). Example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/271056/timeline)

Comment: The example link is 404 (maybe the original post has been deleted and requires 10k rep?).

Comment: @dim Yes migration stubs get auto-deleted after 30 days so any example link will eventually become 10k-only.