# Why was my vim question moved to SU?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope, superuser

> [Vim questions: do they belong to Stack Overflow or Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su) - Discussing which site vim questions should be asked.
>
> [Are questions about vi, vim, and other clones on-topic here?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309/are-questions-about-vi-vim-and-other-clones-on-topic-here/311#311) - Discussing whether vim is on topic at http://unix.stackexchange.com

My question [Upgrading Vim on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/309594/upgrading-vim-on-mac-os-x) regarding vim boiled down to, what I believe, is a developer issue.  The `$PATH` value in your `~/.bash_profile` and using an IDE.  Not only that but the community has seemed to agree that SO is the place for vim questions.

I don't particularly care if the question gets moved back to SO.  I'd just like to know, **why was it moved in the first place?**  What aspect of my question made it more suitable for SU?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question is neither about programming, nor about using `vim`, both of which would qualify it for SO. It's about how to get your OS to pick up a specific executable when you call it without a qualified path. It's not specific to `vim`, nor something specific to developers at all.

So it's a better fit for SU.