# Why was this vim question migrated to SU?

Tags: discussion, migration

Why was this [vim question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617390/vim-copy-delete-then-paste?noredirect=1) migrated to SuperUser?  It's clearly about how to use the editor.  I thought [**it was decided**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su) that vim questions belonged on SO.  Sorry if the rules have changed since I last checked, but SO is where I've been doing all my vim Q&A on the network.

Comment: I don't see how that Q directly relates to actual programming in any way, except that it is a tool to assist with code writing.  (rhetorical) Would *"How do I turn on syntax highlighting in Vim?"* be appropriate for SO?  Thats my 2c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example in the question used code, but beyond that there wasn't really anything programmer-specific about the question. It picked up a flag for migration to SU (which admittedly was disputed by another user) and I agreed.

I wasn't aware of the meta discussion you linked to that made all Vim questions on-topic by consensus on SO, but I'll keep it in mind for the future unless new consensus is established here. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 3):

`vim` feels very much like a programmer tool to me -- never mind that it is wonderful for books or papers or email or whatever else needs editing -- so I'm surprised that it was migrated to Superuser.

If your example had been sentences of prose I could understand the migration -- even though everyone I know who uses `vim` is also a programmer.