# Where do Vim questions belong and what is the community opinion about answering your own?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago, I stumbled onto a nice announcement: *Vim ported to mobile devices*. Since it was news at a time, I decided to post [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8943969/827263) and give [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943992/827263) right afterwards about it.

From what I understood,

[Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)
[Vim questions: SO or SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su)

neither Vim related topics are offtopic on SO, nor is answering your own forbidden (from the FAQ, my understanding is that it is actually encouraged, as long as the answer contains useful information).

So why was the question closed offtopic, or at all for that matter?

*The moderator who closed it isn't answering, so I'm asking here ...*

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question?

Comment: I'm assuming [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943969/is-there-a-vim-port-for-mobile-devices)?

Comment: @YannisRizos - Yup, sorry about that - forgot.

Comment: Related: [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497)

Comment: A lot of the comments are saying that this was self-promotion. @ldigas, are you associated with this product?

Comment: @KeithThompson - (I've answered that below in the comments) Not in any way, apart from being a Vim user (but on Windows). I don't even own any of Apple's products.

Comment: But what is interesting is that this was closed under the presumption of being offtopic, then we switched to it not being a question, now it's self promotion. I don't mind if someone has a different opinion, and says "I just didn't like it, so I voted for closing". But this is bs ... masking every possible reason in hope one will "pass" ...

Comment: ... the problem with rules is that you have to stand by them even when you don't like it ... otherwise they're not rules, they're just someone's will ...

Comment: @ldigas You see switching rationales, I see myriad reasons it was a bad question.  The advantage of community governance is that the community can weed out bad content without having to explain its actions to some higher authority.

Comment: @ldigas I sincerely don't get the sense that you're hoping to understand why your question was closed at this point.  The community gave you indirect feedback about the quality of the question by closing and deleting it, and then plenty of direct feedback in this discussion. If you really don't see how your question differs from all the unclosed questions on SO and are looking for guidance, you need to make that clearer.  If you're just seeking vindication, I don't think you're going to find much  satisfaction here.

Comment: @blahdiblah - ah, so it was "It sucked, I voted for closing" reason. I have no quarrels with that. The only thing I mind is them being closed under a false reason of /see the list of all mentioned below/ when it is actually someone's dislikeness for it, the real reason.

Comment: but from what I gather, the dislikeness is expressed by downvoting the question. For closing you must have justification.

Answer (score 7):

**That wasn't a real question.**

There's nothing to indicate that anyone ever actually wanted to know whether there was a Vim port for mobile devices.  You arranged that news into the Q&A format that SO uses, but it was still just an announcement.

This question here on meta also suggests that you might want to have a closer look at the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Your question wasn't closed because of anything to do with Vim or self-answers.

Comment: And even if there was a demand, SO wasn't the place for it. It was simply off-topic.

Comment: "to indicate that anyone ever actually wanted to know ..." ?! I didn't see that as a requirement anywhere. I don't want to know the answers to half of the questions that gets posted and self-answered, but don't see anyone closing them.

Comment: @ldigas And I [quote](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: @ldigas: "I didn't see that as a requirement anywhere." It's implicit by the definition of the word "question" that someone actually wants the answer. You didn't want the answer; you were just trying to force a news post into Stack Overflow's Q&A style. That's an abuse of the site; the question deserved to be closed and even deleted.

Comment: @NicolBolas - how does that differ from all other self-answerable questions (answered a minute after)? It is obvious the author already knew the answer before posting the question.

Comment: @blahdiblah - first answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question "Just post your answer immediately after you post the question. Like you say, phrase it as a request for comments to improve your solution. Your intentions are clear --- I wouldn't think you were trying to generate reputation."

Comment: @blahdiblah - It was practical, it was answerable, it was a question. And was I in a situation to have an iPad I would've had a problem of not having Vim. So what's the problem?

Comment: @Idigas: Honestly? Who would come *here* for information on whether Vim is available for iPad? Why not just search the App Store and see "[oh look, they have Vim](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vim/id492668168?mt=8)."

Comment: @ldigas Two out of three isn't enough.  Practical? Maybe.  Answerable? Yes.  Actual problem? *Definitely not.*

Comment: @ldigas: Fine. It shouldn't be closed as "Not a question." It should be *deleted as spam*. It even looks like an Apple ad, with giant pictures of iPads running Vim on them. This is not a place to advertise for your tool and platform of choice.

Comment: @animuson - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725/favorite-gvim-plugins-scripts ... Why not just search www.vim.org ?! Any answer can be found with enough searching and experimenting. I thought we've passed that conclusion.

Comment: @blahdiblah - It was not practical? Elaborate please. Actual problem? Reply to my previous comment regarding this point.

Comment: @ldigas That question would be closed if it were asked today.

Comment: @NicolBolas - It is Vim running on iPad. Just how *is it supposed to look like* than Vim running on an iPad? You're not making any sense with that sentence. (I don't use nor own any of Apple's products).

Comment: @Idigas: It will probably get closed now, since it's been brought to light.

Comment: @ldigas: That gvim question is a perfect example of an old question that should have been closed long ago but wasn't. Thanks for bringing it to someone's attention; perhaps now it can be properly closed. And no, just because you can find a question on the site that breaks the rules does *not* mean you get to too.

Comment: @blahdiblah - Could you elaborate on the reason, as previously asked?

Comment: Ah, you ment the other one ... yes, well, the retroactive application of rules is a specialty of SE sites. I can provide dozens of other examples if you're in that sort of mood, but regarding mine - I'm still waiting for your answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas - At the time of posting, that question (and a plethora of  others) was regarded as a very good question. By retroactive application of "law", no question will ever stay open ... (been here long enough, seen plenty of examples).

Comment: ... still waiting, once you figure it out ... (will check for future comments tomorrow)

Comment: @ldigas Questions should be about "actual problems that you face."  You've made clear that your question was not an actual problem that you faced.  I'm not sure how to make that clearer.

Comment: @blahdiblah - Any question that gets answered immediatelly is not about an "actual problem that you face", since the very fact that you answered it right afterwards implies that you don't longer have that as a problem. I.e. you solved it already. So you're putting it here as a question/answer for others, or as a future reference for yourself. My question/answer satisfies both those "demands".

Comment: @ldigas The crucial difference is that someone *did* face that problem.  Your justification for your question rests on the notion that someone *might* face that problem.  The difference is important.

Comment: @blahdiblah - Who did? (find examples of self-answered questions) Author posts question, a minute later - author posts answer. What evidence do you have that anyone ever faced that problem?

Comment: @Idigas as others have already said, the problem here is not the self-answer, but the promotional aspect. `The community generally frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam, so be careful. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it.` your post is obviously overt self-promotion, and the community tends to dislike that, even though it's about a free product (which I think is great).

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm - (Others? What others? Your comment was the first on that ...) But, I digress ... as I was saying ... I have no Apple's products, am in no way connected to it, nor to Vim in any way (apart from using it, but on Windows) ... so how can it be self-promotion?

Comment: @ldigas: "At the time of posting, that question (and a plethora of others) was regarded as a very good question. By retroactive application of "law", no question will ever stay open" The way a wiki works is by *correcting* the past. In that way, it becomes a better source of information. If rules were lax in the past, that doesn't mean those rules were bad. It simply means that they weren't enforced. Enforcing them now is good. And if your justification for your post is "other people do it"... well, that's not a good justification, and your spam deserves to be deleted.

Comment: @NicolBolas - "if the rules were lax in the past, that doesn't mean those rules were bad" -
but the rules were not "lax in the past". Those rules did not exist. So how can
we abide by them, if they do not exist?  It is like charging someone for fast
driving on the part of the road, which at that time had no speed limit? And then
fining him 20 years later, because now it does.

Comment: Wikipedia, since the past is not exactly known to us, tries to describe it to
the best of its contributors knowledge, when new discoveries are made. It is a
search of the absolute truth ... 
... which is not analoguous to this site. There is no absolute truth here. When
someone asks a question which fits into every "rule of what should not be asked"
at that time, it shouldn't be closed in the future, for that individual has no
way of knowing what this site is going to "evolve into" ... he acted with the

Comment: best of intentions at the time of writing. How can you say this site aims with
the goal of "keeping knowledge for future reference" when it deletes the past?
How can you keep the history when you keep changing it?  Wikipedia does not

delete history, it keeps all of it ... this site doesn't, so every new
incarnation is the new history of what was and what wasn't.

Besides, as shown above, I still do not see which one I've broken ... apart
from setting a stir amongst the few of you (and there is no rule against that,
mind you).