# Do questions about using editors belong on Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope, superuser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vim questions: do they belong to Stack Overflow or Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user)

I've seen a lot of "How do I do X in emacs / vim?" type of questions on Stack Overflow. I know both are extensible editors and hence these questions could be programming related, but mostly they are about existing commands and preprogrammed functionality which the user doesn't know about.

Where do you think people should ask these?

Comment: Oh, I can see there are some similar questions around. Nevermind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say this question would be fair game for Stack Overflow. An editor is a tool used in the development process; asking questions related to their use (as long as they somehow relate to the development process) is perfectly acceptable on StackOverflow.

What I *wouldn't* consider fair game is if you asked something like, "Is there a good text editor for Mac OS X that can organize HTML tags?" Hardware and/or software-specific questions like these belong on superuser instead.

Comment: RTFM questions shouldn't be dumped on superuser either. Superuser has a broader scope than SO, but it shouldn't be where low-quality questions go to die.

Comment: @CodeGnome, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't mean to suggest that superuser is a good place to ask crappy, no-effort questions... I was only using that as an example to illustrate the difference between superuser and StackOverflow :). I've updated my answer with a new example... hope it's OK with you!