# Should text editors questions be migrated to SU?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do questions about using editors belong on Stack Overflow or Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136465/do-questions-about-using-editors-belong-on-stack-overflow-or-super-user)

I came across these question when going over the `notepad++` and `sublimetext2` tags (these are only from the first page):

- [notepad++ tab to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573852/notepad-tab-to-left)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323932/i-want-to-open-new-notepad-with-new-window
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752344/how-do-i-skip-to-the-end-of-a-bracket-in-notepad
- [Sublime as default editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450895/sublime-as-default-editor)
- [Sublime Text from Command Line (Win7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line-win7)
- [Sublime text editor: how to select all instances of selected region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162047/sublime-text-how-to-select-all-instances)
- [Sublime Text 2 - Show file navigation in sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995591/sublime-text-2-show-file-navigation-in-sidebar)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270121/issues-with-sublime-text-2-sidebar

These questions are not programming-related, but more computer-software-operating-related. I'm not talking about Regex-related questions. It seems to me that the questions I listed above should be on SuperUser rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

While there might be some gray area, text editors appear to fall within the tools [area of the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

We can't all be [real programmers](http://xkcd.com/378/).