# Regex questions on SU

Tags: discussion, scope, superuser, site-crossover

Which Regex-related questions on SU should be migrated to SO and which shouldn't?

For example, this question should definitely be on SU: [Interactive regex find highliting in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/459167/interactive-regex-find-highliting-in-notepad)

But where do questions like these belong?

- [Regex Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/452614/regex-notepad) (Not programming-related)
- [Notepad++ Find & Replace (with regex) issue](https://superuser.com/questions/407635/notepad-find-replace-with-regex-issue) (Not programming-related)
- [How to remove all the duplicated words on every line using Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/454046/how-to-remove-all-the-duplicated-words-on-every-line-using-notepad) (Not programming-related)
- [Notepad++: Regex issue](https://superuser.com/questions/451927/notepad-regex-issue) (Somewhat programming-related)

Comment: Why are they off topic from Super User?

Comment: Are the questions themselves off-topic for SU? (I don't participate there, so I don't know). If not, then none of them should be migrated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a question is specifically about the use of regex **in program code**, then it belongs on Stack Overflow. If it's about regex find-and-replace in, say, a text editor, then as far as I'm aware it's very much on topic for SU.

This seems to be more of an issue with Notepad++ questions than regex questions. As somebody who regularly looks at [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) questions (it's one of my favorite tags on both sites), I'm quite torn. Namely, the software itself was made for use by programmers, but it is often used in non-programming contexts such as general text editing purposes, as you describe. Combined with the general unawareness that questions about programming tools are, in fact, on topic for SO, we get tons of unfulfilled close votes for [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) questions on SO. I'm not active on SU though, so I'm not sure how often questions get migrated from there to here, if ever.

But personally, I consider questions about Notepad++ on topic for *both* SO and SU; wherever a question is asked, I don't see much of a *need* to migrate it to one or the other unless explicitly requested by the asker. Since they're on SU already, I'd say it's OK to keep them where they are. It just happens by coincidence that the nature of Notepad++ as a code editor means questions about it are on topic for SO as well as SU.

Comment: Oh, I see you'd just asked [a question about text editors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149597/should-text-editors-questions-be-migrated-to-su) earlier on.

Comment: Yeah. I read some answers from previous similar questions and they've said pretty much everything you said, I guess if it's not specific to programming, then it belongs on both sites.