# Make "What kind of questions can I ask here" rule more explicit

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

It seems to me that some questions fit on StackOverflow as well as they do on some sister sites.  As a result, such questions are cluttered with comments like "this belongs on unix.se, superuser, etc".

[This question on benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) has prompted my request, though vim questions raise similar concerns, [as has seen here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user).

So my request is to update the Stackoverflow FAQ#questions section to address this extra comment-noise.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add the statement "Some questions regarding programmer tools may fit on other Stack Exchange sites.  So long as they still meet the site guidelines, they're acceptable for StackOverflow".